# Why didn't Fischer recognise Saito?

Tags: inception

In the third level of the dream (the Snow Fortress) Saito, a major competitor of Fischer interacts with Fischer, but for some reason Fischer simply doesn't notice.

**Surely he would know who Saito is, so why did he go with him or trust him? Did he just not recognise him?**

Answer (score 7):

### Because he didn't realize that he is dreaming

Fischer boards a plane to LA to join his family for his father's funeral. In the **exact** same plane, Cobb, Ariadne, Arthur, Saito, Eames and Yusuf are boarded too and they are all sitting in **nearby seats**. Fischer knows that he is boarding the same plane with his business opponent, though he doesn't quarrel with him; Saito hasn't initiated yet his plan to destroy the former's company and even if he did, Fischer wouldn't do anything other than maybe ask to sit in a different seat, away of him.

By the time they enter the first level of the dream, Fischer meets Saito, Eames and Yusuf in the taxi. Not only does he fail to remember Saito, he fails to recognize everybody else, though merely moments before, he saw them sitting next to him at the *real* plane. If he was to understand and question Saito's motives, then the same applies for everybody else.

I think that (even though it is not addressed in the movie), Fischer could only understand that something is going wrong in the early dream levels. As long as they are entering into deeper levels, they are also diving deeper into his subconscious. Fischer only focuses on his ultimate target (to find what his father left him), which obscures anything other that might be considered irrelevant (his company, his whereabouts, what the others are talking about etc.).

By the time they are at the third level (where everybody is on Fischer's side), he does not seem to question why Saito, Eames and Arthur aid him, though in a previous dream level, they were the ones that kidnapped him. That brings us to the conclusion that **he cannot recall** this previous knowledge. *He is dreaming.* He can neither persevere the full dream spectrum, nor he can remember the previous dreams and what was happening in then. And if we go one step further, he cannot recall his reality, either. Dreams are shaped of what interests us and sometimes they are influenced by what we have seen prior to falling asleep. Since a regular person would not rationally think that "what I am seeing right now is influenced by what I saw before I went to bed", then the same applies to Fischer.

Keep in mind that, at the baggage pick-up point, Fischer seems to be having a deja-vu moment (where he looks at Cobb, as if he was slightly familiar), though he quickly turns his head away. If he cannot recognize Cobb, with whom he actively shared **three** dream levels (second, third and limbo), then in a similar fashion he wouldn't be able to find out who Saito is.

Comment: I think even in the first level they were in the same cab they hijacked to kidnap Fischer... Why not then.... It is a loop hole guys....

Answer (score 2):

## It's not certain that Fischer knows Saito by sight.

Fischer Morrow is the largest competitor to Saito's company (Proclus Global), but perhaps there are many companies about the same size as Proclus Global, all of which are not able to compete with Fischer Morrow.  If there are, say, [10-20 companies](https://www.statista.com/statistics/263424/the-largest-energy-utility-companies-worldwide-based-on-market-value/]) in the same boat, Fischer wouldn't have necessarily met all of their CEOs.

Even if Fischer knows Saito's name and has seen pictures of him, he wouldn't necessarily recognize him in person.

Another thing to remember is that the film doesn't state that Robert is the CEO of Fischer Morrow.  I don't think his job title is stated, only that he's the heir of the conglomerate.  It's possible that he's not that involved in running the business, and therefore might not even know Saito by name or appearance.

EDIT:  [The script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Inception.html) is pretty clear about Saito's company's being the only real competitor to Fisher Morrow:

> Fischer Morrow has the regulators in their pockets. We're the last
>   company standing between them and total energy dominance and we can no
>   longer compete.

Also, given this...

> Robert Fischer, 32. Heir to the Fischer Morrow energy conglomerate. 
>   **He's spent his whole life being groomed as successor**-breaking up his
>   father's empire will take a radical shift in his thinking.

You would *think* that Robert would at least know *of* Saito.  But it's still possible that Robert never met Saito in person.

Comment: Also, I got the impression that Saito is a high-ranking employee of his company but not one of the owners or bosses. Which would make sense as the bosses would be busy running the company and probably wouldn't want to be seen together with known high-profile extractors like Cobb and Arthur. Saito might be considered expandable and be the fall guy if the whole thing gets discovered. When he says "I bought the airline" he might have meant that he told his bosses he needs it to complete his mission.

Comment: Come on.. He was the owner of the company....